# Como armazenar o valor de um input type number em uma variável JS

Tags: javascript

Não consigo armazenar o value do input na minha variável. Como devo proceder? Meu código abaixo:

```
<input type="number" id="numero">
<input type="button" class="adicionar" value="Comprar" onclick="add()" />

<script>
    function add(){
        var quantidade = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value); 
        console.log("Value: "+quantidade);
</script>
```

Quero alterar o value do input e a minha variável alterar também quando eu clicar no botão.

Answer (score 2):

Só faltou você fechar as chaves, porem existe uma propriedade `onchange`.
Com a propriedade `onchange` a cada vez que você alterar o valor do input ele chama sua funçao `add()`, assim alterando junto o `input` ele ira alterar sua variável junto;

```html
<input type="number" id="numero" onchange="add()">
<input type="button" class="adicionar" value="Comprar" onclick="add()">

<h1 id="valor"></h1>

<script>
    function add(){
        var quantidade = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value); 
        console.log("Value: "+quantidade);
        document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = quantidade;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: É verdade, deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você fechar as chaves.

```html
<input type="number" id="numero">
<input type="button" class="adicionar" value="Comprar" onclick="add()" />

<script>
    function add(){
        var quantidade = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value); 
        console.log("Value: "+quantidade);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Verdade, erro bobo. Valeu pela ajuda!